# Theory question: If I pass an object into a function via a parameter, is that still considered "dependency injection"?

Tags: javascript, theory

In the following example, I am declaring an object and a consumer of the object. I then call the function, passing in the required object.

Is this considered dependency injection?
If not, what is it called when managing dependencies this way?

```
const databaseConnection = {
    action() {
        // ...
    }
}

function useIt(db) {
    db.action()
}

useIt(myDep)
```

Comment: You could always create a constructor for the consumer that accepts that object type and then you could do constructor injection. After you edited your post, I don't believe this is considered dependency injection. (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-7578c84fa88f)

Comment: Would we have to like, also inject the word 'action' via an interface or injector or whatever to make this truely decoupled? At the moment useIt() still knows that whatever gets passed in, has a method named action. Or am I mixing up concepts?

Comment: From what I read on [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection): **Dependency injection** is a technique whereby one object (or static method) supplies the dependencies of another object. Is this the case in your example above? If yes, then this will mean the answer will be "Yes" as well.